# Installing Asterisk extra sounds on Fedora 23

Tags: installation, packages, asterisk, pbx, dnf

On Fedora 23 I found that the Asterisk "extra" sounds don't seem to be included in the main DNF repos.  How can I install the "extra" sounds using DNF?  For example, I would like to be able to do: `dnf install asterisk-extra-sounds-en-gsm`.  Do I need to put something in /etc/yum.repos.d or in /etc/dnf?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds package is just files for /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/ folder

Simplest way is just download tar archive and unpack.

http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/sounds/releases